# Docusign APi Sender Issue

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusign-sdk

In docusign api, we are using our project DMS with docusign php api and I have a doubt whenever a sender like an initiator sends a document by email to any two users to sign and then when these two users sign the same from their emails completely ,they got new emails from DocuSign automatically stating their document signatures are completed but however the same email is not sent back to that initiator with the completed status.

Please let me know how to enable the above scenario where the same email with completed status should go back to the sender like the initiator also.

thanks and regards,
Pankaj

The email which has been sent to number of recipients with completed status should come back to the sender

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider here:
First, these two signers, do they sign at the same time, this is the **routing_order** property that if set will make it so that they sign in order. Which means that the emails will get to both recipients at the same time after the singer with the higher signing order signs the envelope (make sure, we didn't see your code, that you send a single envelope to two recipients, not two envelopes).

Your main issue, however, is how the sender, the person using the DocuSign account to send envelopes can ensure they can get back the envelope at the end. There are options to set for this, you have to go to the "Settings" portion of the web app (for administrators) and go to the "Email Notifications" menu on the left and ensure you have it selected.
[image]

Lastly, you can just add the sender as CC for the envelope, that's a common practice and ensures that the sender gets a copy at the end.